# FourSquare API doesn't support CORS

Tags: javascript, rest, foursquare, cors

The FourSquare API documentation states that it supports CORS. However calling to the /users/ endpoints clearly states that only GET requests are supported:

```
curl -X OPTIONS -i "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins?oauth_token=CLIENT_OAUTH_TOKEN"

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, private, no-store
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 13 Feb 2013 04:31:54 GMT
Expires: Wed, 13 Feb 2013 04:31:54 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Tracer-Time: 17
Content-Length: 104
Connection: keep-alive

{"meta":{"code":405,"errorType":"other","errorDetail":"This endpoint only supports GET."},"response":{}}
```

Is this just particular to these API endpoints or has something changed?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked into all the methods in the FourSquare API, but my guess is that FourSquare doesn't need to support preflight requests because all their API requests are simple. The [docs here](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#requests) suggest that the API only supports GET and POST. If those requests don't have any custom headers, they will never need a preflight request.

Comment: Thanks Monsur - however if doing an XHR GET then the browser does this preflight OPTIONS request and fails.

Comment: Can you share your request headers for the preflight? There could be some additional headers on the request (which may or may not be expected).

Comment: Here is an example of a client side app that should work: http://bl.ocks.org/ajturner/a66ae1a71c43fa7b8a33

Comment: That sample seems to be failing for non-CORS reasons. It looks like FourSquare prevents its authentication frame from being embedded in an iframe by setting the `X-Frame-Options` header to `DENY`. You can see the error by looking in the console.log.

Comment: This - " If those requests don't have any custom headers, they will never need a preflight request." - helped me a lot because I had a no-cache header and a postman generated header which enabled the preflight request. Thanks!